# Law of Large Numbers for the reciprocal

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Assume $(X_i)_{i\geq1}$ and $(Y_i)_{i\geq1}$ are two independent sequences of i.i.d. random variables such that $\mathbb E[X^k]<\infty$ and $\mathbb E[Y^k]<\infty$ $\forall k\geq1$.

I am wondering if there is there a straightforward way to prove that
\begin{equation}
\frac{Y_n}{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i} \stackrel{\mathbb P}{\rightarrow}0.
\end{equation}

The only approach that comes to my mind is using some approximation theorem to write $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i = n\mathbb E[X] + \varepsilon_n$, where $\varepsilon_n\stackrel{\mathbb P}{\rightarrow}0$, but this seems unnecessarily complicated. Is there any simpler approach?

Comment: You need to add a condition that excludes the case of $P(X_i = 0) = 1$. For example, you could add that $0 < \Bbb{E}[X^2] < \infty$. And once you do that, the problem becomes a straightforward application of the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: @MarkFischler That seems to work! Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write
\begin{align}
   \frac{Y_n}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} &=
      \frac{Y_n/n}{(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)/n} \;.
\end{align}
If $\mathbb{E}[|X|]<\infty$, we have, by the law of large numbers, $(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)/n\to\mathbb{E}[X]$ almost surely (or in probability).  If $\mathbb{P}(|Y|<\infty)=1$, you also have $Y_n/n\to 0$ in probability. You get the desired convergence in probability provided $\mathbb{E}[X]\neq 0$.

If furthermore, $\mathbb{E}[|Y|]<\infty$, you also have almost sure convergence, because
\begin{align}
   \frac{Y_n}{n} &=
      \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}{n}-
      \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Y_i}{n-1}
      \to 0 
\end{align}
almost surely, by the law of large numbers.

Comment: Very simple and elegant. Thank you.